# Select top, random in env odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Is it possible in request env add "Select top" and "radndom" option?

```
test = http.request.env['my.test'].sudo().search([('type','=',1)])[0]

        return http.request.render('my_page', {'test': test})
```

I don't need return all data from database only top 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try parameter **limit**, (and **order** parameter if needed) of search.

test = http.request.env['my.test'].sudo().search([('type','=',1)], **limit=10**)